# Bash script: сравнение и вывод в файл значений

Tags: массивы, grep, bash, файлы

Добрый день!

Имеется два файла, один со списком пользователей, второй - кусок лога, приведенный к более-менее удобоваримому виду (дата, время аутентификации, имя пользователя). Попробовал вывести первое вхождение пользователя в систему командой:

```
grep -m1 user.log < auth.log >time.log
```

получил бороду (завершение команды grep с ошибкой), проверил сразу после этой команды командой `echo $?` (в удачном случае дает результат 0, в неудачном возвращает 1). Подскажите, как реализовать массив, чтобы читал код команды grep, в случае неудачи переходил к следующей строке в файле, а в случае удачи - вставлял строку из auth.log.

Comment: alexlz спасибо сработало

Comment: вместо $i поставил "$i" чтобы имена с точками читал

Comment: Насчёт точек -- опять же -- смотрите grep. Просто точка -- совпадение с любым символом

Comment: А какую собственно ошибку выдаёт grep? Он должен просто тихо возвращать не 0 в случае отсутствия искомой строки.

Answer (score 2):

Что бы учитывать только точные совпадения, я бы сделал следующим образом. Скрипт `check_auth.sh`:

```
USERS=${1:-user.log}
AUTH=${2:-auth.log}

IFS=$'\n'
for user in $(cat $USERS); do

    IFS=" "
    while read -r date name; do
        [[ "$name" == "$user" ]] && echo $date $name && break
    done < $AUTH
done
```

Соответственно, вызывать так:

```
./check_auth.sh user.log auth.log > time.log
```

PS Если только первое и точное совпадение не критично, то можно решить одной строкой:

```
$ grep -f user.log auth.log > time.log
```

UPD. Исправил баг.

UPD2. Окончательный вариант с полным соответствием, в т.ч. пробелами в имени пользователя.

Comment: Остаётся на усмотрение ТС пользователи с точкой внутри и Вася vs Вася1

Comment: Да, с Васей1 проблема... Тут уже только awk, наверное, спасет.

А с точкой у меня не захватывает. Возможно, версия bash другая. Но в любом случае можно написать:

    [[ "$auth" == *"$user"* ]] && echo $auth && break

Да, так, пожалуй, лучше будет.

Comment: Да, с Васей1 проблема... Тут уже только awk, наверное, спасет.

И это пишет автор ответа с использованием регэкспов. Другое дело, что вместо гадания лучше бы знать структуру файла auth.log, и, соответственно, модифицировать регулярное выражение... Но задача эта решается без напряга.

Comment: > И это пишет автор ответа с использованием регэкспов.

Каждый имеет право немного потупить (c) Не помню чья цитата :)

На самом деле в том-то и проблема, что регэкспы не нужны. А если делать через регекспы, то нужно экранирование спецсимволов, а я увы не вижу простого способа для этого.

В общем, обновил, последний вариант должен учитывать все.

Answer (score 1):

Ну с grep'ом надо смотреть, чтобы пользователь Вася не отвечал за грехи пользователя Вася1, а так:

```
>time.log
for i in `<user.log`
  do if $(grep -qm1 $i auth.log)
    then grep -m1 $i auth.log >> time.log 
  fi
done
```

или

```
(for i in `<user.log`
  do if $(grep -qm1 $i auth.log)
    then grep -m1 $i auth.log
  fi
done) >time.log
```

Comment: Зачем дважды делать grep? grep без оборачивания в if приведёт к тому же результату.

Comment: На случай, если автор скрипта решит предпринять какие-то действия кроме/вместо вывода строки.

Comment: Все равно 2 grep - это перебор. 

Можно прочесть результат grep в переменную  res=`grep ...` , ну дальше или анализ $? или || или && - это насколько фантазии хватит.

Comment: @avp согласен

Answer (score 0):

Приведу свой минимальный вариант для случая одно имя на строке

```
while read user ; do
   test -z "$user" && continue
   grep -m1 -F "$user" < auth.log
done < user.log > time.log
```